# router will not connect to printer

Tags: network-share, router, netgear

I have a netgear WGR614 v8 and a Brother HL-2270DW wireless printer.  Yesterday I flashed the router with DD-WRT firmware.  now my printer will not connect.  printer error page says "Connection : Failed (Error : TS-07) The machine cannot detect a WLAN access point/router that has WPS or AOSS enabled.  In the "SES / AOSS / EZ-SETUP / WPS Button" section of my router control panel I enabled "turning off radio".  I disabled the router firewall.  I connected the printer directly to the router with a network cable.  There is no evidence of any communication between the printer and router that I can find.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to connect the printer to the router using [WPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup)? Or are you trying to configure the SSID and key?

Comment: I am trying to print from two windows machines connected to the router.  Before I flashed the router it would show the printer listed among the connected devices in the router admin page.  Now it is gone and when I try to print, windows shows the printer as offline.  Since I have the printer directly connected by network cable I shouldn't need to configure any wireless settings, right?  In any case I havn't been able to find anyplace where I can configure the Brother's network settings.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Follow the directions [here](http://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-set-up-wireless-printing-with-the-brother-hl2270dw/). Select `no` for WPS/AOSS and manually enter the SSID and key.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your printer is trying to locate an access point using WPS while DD-WRT seems not to be configured to support WPS (or may not offer WPS at all, depending on the version used) and the "WPS" button is used to turn off/on the radio interface of the device in your configuration.

As WPS has [known security weaknesses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup#Security), it should not be used, although the DD-WRT implementation seems to address some of the concerns.

You should enter the SSID, the authentication method (WPA2-PSK presumably) and the secret key into the printer's configuration to connect it to your wireless network.

Comment: Thanks, I will attempt to do so.  Still, I don't understand why my network cable doesn't obviate the need for wireless security settings.  I appreciate your help

Comment: @JesseGoodfellow The network cable should work, but there are many potential points of failure - DD-WRT allows for VLANs which you might have configured in a wrong way. Or there is simply a faulty cable or a failure with one of the network interfaces.